# Error in average of $x^2$ from error in average of $x$?

Tags: means, error-propagation, mean-square-error

Is there an easy way to obtain the error in $\langle{x^2}\rangle$ from $\langle{x}\rangle$ or are they independent?

The values of x are from a molecular simulation application, I obtained a set of values of x but I've used block averaging to make them uncorrelated, giving me a standard error in the mean of x.

Awaiting any advice

Thanks

Comment: Do you know anything about $x$? Random variable which can have values $a, -a$ has "error" $a$ while $x^2$ has error $0$.

Comment: @Wilky94 Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted your post but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use
 [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $\LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Comment: The values of x are from a molecular simulation application, I obtained a set of values of x but I've used block averaging to make them uncorrelated, giving me a standard error in the mean of x.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that if $z=xy$ then the errors add in quadrature: $$\left(\frac{\sigma_{z}}{\bar{z}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sigma_{x}}{\bar{x}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sigma_{y}}{\bar{y}}\right)^2$$

Now if $z=x^2$$$\sigma_{x^2}=\sqrt{2\frac{\bar{x}^2}{\sigma_{x}^2}}$$

Comment: Are you sure this is for the error in the mean of x^2 because my error in the mean of x is around 0.0002 so this formula will give huge errors..